# How to harden portable Tor Browser installation (SELinux, sandbox)?

Tags: linux, tor, firefox, hardening, selinux

#### tldr

How can I define a SELinux policy, that limits filesystem access of portable Tor Browser to its installation directory, say `/home/user/.local/opt/tor-browser_en-US`?

How might Tor Browser be hardened even further (X11 Window system, Tor process) - in this sense what about [`sandbox`/`policycoreutils-sandbox`](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1578673)?

*Threat model*:
falling victim to (Zero Day) exploits by accident via Browser, JavaScript or PDF reader during normal everyday surfing of random pages.

#### More infos

I would like to add a "last barrier of protection" sandbox to my browser installation. Currently, an exploit gives full write permission to the `/home` directory and more - test it by typing `file:///home/<user>` in the address bar.

My linux distro already comes with SELinux included, so this might be a good candidate for hardening.

After having watched the excellent talk ["Security-enhanced Linux for mere mortals - 2015 Red Hat Summit"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cNoVgDqqJmM) by Thomas Cameron, I am able to solve basic problems via `semanage`, adjusting file or mount context types. Though creation of new policies is a different beast. What I did:

- try to learn from existent other Firefox installation rules → unfortunately it has a generic `bin_t` type:

  ```
  ls -alZ /usr/bin/firefox
  -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0 7681 May 10 18:08 /usr/bin/firefox
  ```
- there is a [`torbrowser-launcher`](https://github.com/micahflee/torbrowser-launcher) package by Micah Lee → does not include any SELinux policies
- [`sandbox`/`policycoreutils-sandbox`](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1578673) → not sure, how it relates to SELinux policies? Is this a simple, sandbox-like alternative for desktop apps akin to [firejail](https://github.com/netblue30/firejail)?

Thanks!

---

#### Update

I tried out the [SELinux sandbox](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1578673), which seems to work with Firefox (isolates X11 as well):

```
sandbox -t sandbox_web_t -H /tmp/sandbox/home -T /tmp/sandbox/tmp -X firefox
```

Unfortunately, Tor Browser errors:

```
sandbox \
-t sandbox_net_t -t sandbox_web_t -t sandbox_net_client_t \
-H $tor_dir \
-T /tmp/sandbox/tmp \
-X -w 1920x1080 \
$tor_dir/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser
```

> dbus[7536]: Unable to set up transient service directory: Failed to create directory /run/user/1000/dbus-1: Permission denied
>
> dbus-daemon[7536]: Cannot setup inotify for '/usr/share/dbus-1/session.d'; error 'Permission denied'

Weirdly, Firefox shows the same error, but works. Tor Browser also begins to start a window, then aborts and exits. `-t sandbox_net_t -t sandbox_net_client_t` has been added with the purpose of the Tor process to work in the sandbox.

Comment: Note that apparmor may also be supported by your distro. It has comparable results to SELinux but is a bit easier, and it may have installed/installable profiles for Tor browser or at least Firefox.

Comment: @multithr3at3d thanks for the hint. yeah this probably would be my way to go with a distro like Ubuntu, which has Apparmor preinstalled. Though SELinux is so tightly integrated with distros as RHEL, CentOS, Fedora that it would be a shame to not try to use it first.